# wireless where to scan

Tags: wifi, channel

I am using a wireless network scanner to analyze signal strength around my place and assign the best channel on my AP which is not overlapped with other APs.
Where is the best place to scan; near the AP or near the laptop's desk? I get different results. Around AP the optimal channel is X which is not the best if I consider measurements around the desk, and vice versa.
Any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi is two-way communication. If you use many wireless devices at many location, then you should configure your AP's channel that's less overlapped with any APs around itself.

If Wi-Fi signal at your desk is not good when you configure your AP as describe above.
You might use directional Wi-Fi antenna to solve this problem. (You may attach directional Wi-Fi antenna with USB Wi-Fi adapter.)